# Element LinearLayout is not allowed in CardView

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

Note: **PLEASE READ THE QUESTION** before mark it as duplicate! I've mentioned that the similar question has not solved my problem.

---

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` for my layout xml. However when I place a `LinearLayout` within the `CardView`, Android Studio gives me the following error "***Element LinearLayout is not allowed here***".

In fact **ANY** types of widgets (like TextView) would cause this error, I have tried solutions from [LinearLayout flagged if used in CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440887/linearlayout-flagged-if-used-in-cardview)  link, which was to restart Android Studio. But it did not work. Below is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And I will also post a screenshot!

[image]

What could be the problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinearLayout flagged if used in CardView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440887/linearlayout-flagged-if-used-in-cardview)

Comment: I've already mentioned in the question that I've looked into that link and it did not solve my problem.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the link when I marked it as duplicate. Seems that there is an open issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81362, which Android Studio version do you use?

Comment: I did mention the link, it's just that I did not actually name it as " LinearLayout flagged if used in CardView". I am using 1.5 RC 1, but the same thing was happening before this version.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050016/views-getting-flagged-inside-cardview) suggests to use a backup version of your project, which is not a acceptable workaround, but maybe it'll help you.

Comment: And I assume you already tried the obvious solutions - clean&rebuild, invalidate cache & restart, maybe computer reboot, trying to do this in a new layout file/deleting this layout file & creating a new one..?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and while I was doing what you suggested I found out that AS could not compile CardView widget because correct dependency was not added. I had to add `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'` in my gradle file.

Comment: If you post your comments as answer I will upvote & accept it as answer, thanks!

Comment: Apart from this suggestions, refer to my answer here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440887/linearlayout-flagged-if-used-in-cardview/57663140#57663140

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, a collection of suggestions, just to be sure:

- restart AS
- invalidating Caches & restart
- **Check if the right dependencies are added**
- clean & rebuild of project
- try same code in another file/project
- trying to find a backup of your project
- maybe computer reboot

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` with `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the Gradle dependency is added properly for the CardView.

**In build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

**And then in the XML**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you did not inter constrains(magic stick) to card view  because it will add constrains to card view and prevent any linear layout.